# How to move only one side of a cube in object mode - equivalent of stretching the cube in that direction without moving other faces

Tags: modeling

Having come from another CAD package, I am accustomed to being able to identify a cuboid and grow it in one direction i.e. stretch the 'scale' in this dimension, but on one side of the cube only.  I am sure that this can be done easily (I can see ways using extrude, but then there is a join required etc... - several commands, and cumbersome).
What am I missing?   Ideally this should be available in block mode, not edit mode, similarly to the scale, move and rotate functions.
Help!

Comment: switch the Transfom Pivot Point to 3D Cursor?

Comment: Not sure - trying to do it in one action, as I was used to in the older software.  It seems a trivial thing to ask, but I am stumped.  I really should just be able to 'grab' that face and pull, in essence.  It is a very useful thing to do to adjust an added bit in a design, I feel.

Answer (score 6):

You can just move the face in *Edit* mode:

[image]

If you want to do it in *Object* mode, put the 3D cursor on the face that is supposed to be the pivot point:

[image]

go into the *Transform Pivot Point* panel and choose *3D Cursor* (or keyboard shortcut <kbd>.</kbd> to get the pie menu:

[image]

then scale on the axis you want (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> here):

[image]

Comment: Great - thank you.  I am still getting to grips with the ins and outs of the package, and I appreciate your patience.  I knew that there had to be an easy way, but I am trying to learn enough to get going with the models that I wish to create for 3D printing.  I do not intend to go further into the advanced features, but the package is impressive.

Comment: My edit not intended as a crit. of this answer, it's what @VJM wants... but....

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as if 'Normal' should be one of your favourite Transform Orientations?

- <kbd>,</kbd> comma, set Transform Orientation to 'Normal'
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will move any selected face along its normal.

As @moonboots points out, there is a way to scale in Object Mode, if you insist, but it's not a habit I would want to get into...

- You have to define a pivot
- If the face is skewed to the World, and to its own object axis, you have to define a scaling orientation
- Your object will be left with a non-uniform Object-level scale, which will probably have to be applied in order not to mess up modifiers, texture-spaces, etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you - I will use Edit Mode.  I have been playing with this, and am now reasonably comfortable with the processes.  It is just very different from the package I was using previously - much more powerful and with many nice features, but perhaps this makes the simple operations (that I have grown accustomed to using) require more key strokes.  I really appreciate the rapid response, and must apologise for my lack of knowledge of the package and its terminology (which, of course, is different).  I hope to gain proficiency as time progresses!

Comment: @VJM Apologise? What for? That's why BSE is here. The Blender learning curve is a bit steep, and it's been notorious for an overloaded keymap. That has been reduced in recent versions, but I wouldn't wish it away. Once learned, it's a Pretty Damn Quick way to work.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the balance that needs to be stuck.  With respect, I found the previous user interface that I used on another program much more intuitive, and remarkably fast (my colleagues felt the same).  Let's hope I can get up to speed quickly; I know what I want to do, and it is very limited in scope.  Only gave up on the other program because of poor shape decomposition, which caused issues in stl files.